# How to include trailing spaces on a query string parameter or route?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an autocomplete input field which submits the string entered so far to the back end. I tried both the below approaches (with the api method coded accordingly) where `query` contains the string entered so far:

```
$.ajax("/api/books/"+query)...
```

and

```
$.ajax("/api/books/?"+query) ...
```

In both cases, any trailing space is not included. For example, "test " will submit "test". As a result, I am unable to exclude results like "testing" when the input string is "test ".

Is it a browser or jQuery issue and is there a way to enable trailing spaces?

PS: An input string of "test a" works fine.

Comment: From briefly looking over the jQuery source, I don't see anything immediately that stands out as trimming the URL, however it seems like you probably aren't properly URL encoding the value for the query string, which would mean you're passing a literal value of `"test "` when `"test%20"` or `"test+"` would be appropriate.

Comment: I inspected, and "test a" was sent as "test%20a" but "test " was sent as "test".  Anyway, I found the answer, and it is to use the `data` parameter.

Comment: Yes, well the `data` parameter automatically encodes data into a proper query string for `GET` requests, so that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `data` parameter instead of putting it on the url:

```
$.ajax({ url: "/api/books/", data: { s:query}}) ...
```